# Относительные ссылки css

Tags: php, css

Есть сайт site.ru на локальном сервере apache и есть файл page.php и style.css.

Располагаются они вот так:

```
site.ru/page.php
site.ru/css/style.css
```

Ссылка на style.css в файле page.php такая:

```
css/style.css
```

Она работает. Но и исправно работает ссылка:

```
../css/style.css
```

И большего уровня вложенности тоже работает.
Хотя по идее так быть не должно.

Собственно в этом и вопрос. Почему это работает?

Comment: В чем проблема? Наивысшая категория доступная сайту это `/`, где и лежит ваш page.php файл. Подьем на категорию выше по идее ничего не даст. А первый вариант работает по прямой логике.

Comment: Если вы открываете page.php в браузере — покажите точное значение адресной строки (домен можно скрыть, если он секретный), а то я вам как-то не очень верю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Если нужно указать, что файл, на который вы ссылаетесь, находится в родительской папке, используйте символы .. (две точки), они означают подняться на один уровень вверх (в родительскую папку текущего каталога). Далее мы указываем прямой слэш "/", чтобы разделить части пути, и пишем имя нашего файла.
>
> **Примечание**: символы .. можно использовать сколько угодно раз подряд, используя их, вы поднимаетесь каждый раз на одну папку вверх. **Однако, подниматься вверх можно до тех пор, пока не придете в корневую папку своего сайта. Выше этой папки подняться нельзя.**

[Источник](https://puzzleweb.ru/html/8_links2.php)

Comment: Но папка `css` ведь не в родительской папке

Comment: @andreymal почему это? Родительская папка включает файл `page.php` и категорию `css/`.

Comment: @Telion вот именно, они оба находятся в одном каталоге, и этот их родительский каталог уже является текущим — поэтому никакого `../` не нужно

Comment: @andreymal А, в этом плане. Все верно, выход на категорию выше не нужен. Но вопрос был в том почему оно работает.

Comment: Мне кажется, автор просто что-то упускает или не договаривает, но я пока не уверен что

Comment: @Telion апач так работает, не пустит он тебя на уровень выше корня сколько `../` не напиши. Я ж даже жирным это выделил в ответе